# Movement of a 2d character works only in 1 direction

Tags: c++, opengl, character, move, key

Ok my problem is:
I'm working on a 2d game (like mario bros.).. and i'm stuck at character movement
i got the keys implemented.. and got a simple quad to test movement.. but it doesn't really work the way i want to.

when i press 'a' my quad moves left, when i press 'w' my quad moves up.. simple but it works
but if i press 'd' my quad just won't move right.. it just disappears somehow though i've done it the same way as the left key.. and deleting the left key to see if it's influencing the x movement didn't help

thanks in advance.. hope u guys got an idea.. i'm confused

-- as i said.. the other keys work.. but pressing d doesn't move the quad
-- xpos is GLfloat, i also tried float.. no change
-- pressing d makes my quad disappear for some reason

---

```
if (active){        
                            if (keys[VK_ESCAPE])
            {
                done=TRUE;
            }
            if (keys['W'])
            {
                if(!toggle)
                {
                ypos=ypos+1.0;
                toggle=1;
                }
            }
            if (!keys['W'])
                {
                    ypos=0.0;toggle=0;
                }
            if (keys['A'])
            {
                    t_key=1;
                    xpos1=xpos1-0.1f; 
            }                
            if (keys['D'])          
            {
                    t_key=0;
                    xpos2=xpos2-0.1f;
            }   
            else                        
            {
                DrawWorld();                
                DrawChar();
                SwapBuffers(hDC);
            }
```

}

---

```
int DrawChar(GLvoid){
glLoadIdentity();   // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
GLfloat xtrans;
if(t_key){
    xtrans=xpos1;
    xpos2=xpos1;
}
else{
    xtrans=xpos2;
    xpos1=xpos2;
}
GLfloat ytrans=ypos;    
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-30.0f);     // move 5 units into the screen
glTranslatef(xtrans,ytrans,0.0f);
...
```

---

CONLUSION

if there's anybody else having the same problems.. and he only read a few of nehe's tuts instead of doing all the lessons.. (he used the if for the escape only, which works)
here's what u probably got wrong.. put the draw functions and swapbuffers outside the else and delete it.. won't work otherwise

and thnx for the quick answer
solution:

```
if (active){        
                        if (keys[VK_ESCAPE])
        {
            done=TRUE;
        }
        if (keys['W'])
        {
            if(!toggle)
            {
            ypos=ypos+1.0;
            toggle=1;
            }
        }
        if (!keys['W'])
            {
                ypos=0.0;toggle=0;
            }
        if (keys['A'])
        {
                t_key=1;
                xpos1=xpos1-0.1f; 
        }                
        if (keys['D'])          
        {
                t_key=0;
                xpos2=xpos2-0.1f;
        }
            DrawWorld();                
            DrawChar();
            SwapBuffers(hDC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have code like this:

```
if (condition1) 
{
   instruction1
}
if (condition2)
{
   instruction2
} 
else 
{
   instruction3
}
```

Note that the `instruction3` will only be executed if `condition2` evaluates to `false`. In your case `condition2` is `keys['D']`. In other words if you press `D`, the map won't be refreshed. Could that be the problem?

Comment: omg... i feel really embarassed now ^^ I just deleted the else and it works.. thank u very much.. it's always the same.. i'm thinking too complicated